# Getting the difference between two queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a **poorly** designed database. I need to query the table to find the solution for the following issue.

Let's say I have a table like this.

```
+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|     id     | SubCode    | Type         | NumId     |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|      1     | SB1212     | TCH          | 100000000 |
|      1     | SB1212     | APP          | 100000000 |
|      1     | SB1212     | TCH          | 100000001 |
|      1     | SB1212     | APP          | 100000002 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to find the NumId of the people who **only** belong to **Type='TCH'** ( They shouldn't belong to Type='APP').

Note that the NumId is can be duplicated.

I wrote the following query and it's taking too much time to load. This looks like a simple issue but I am working on this for too long to not see a solution now. Can someone point me where I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT NumId 
FROM TeacherSubject 
WHERE SubCode = 'SB1212' 
  AND Type = 'TCH' OR Type = 'APP' 
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT NumId FROM TeacherSubject 
                 WHERE SubCode = 'SB1212' 
                   AND Type = 'APP') 
ORDER BY NumId DESC
```

The output I am expecting is **100000001**. Because **100000000** belongs to TCH and APP types.

Comment: You can select all those with Type= 'TCH' and use `except` with those with Type <> 'TCH'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a CTE

```
with cte as (
select * 
  from TeacherSubject 
 where [Type] = 'APP'
   and Subcode = 'SB1212'
) 
select NumID 
  from TeacherSubject 
 where [Type] = 'TCH'
   and Subcode = 'SB1212' 
   and NumID not in (select NumID from cte)
 order by NumID desc
```

Comment: This is pretty neat and it works like a charm. Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    NumId
    FROM YourTable YT
        WHERE [Type] = 'TCH'
AND SubCode = 'SB1212'
                AND NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT
                        1
                        FROM YourTable
                            WHERE NumId = YT.NumId
                                AND [Type] <> YT.[Type]
AND [SubCode] = YT.SubCode
                )
```

Comment: @Fawzan check this now, it will work more faster now